# Solving the Taylor Polynomial of Degree 2 for f(x) = $xe^x$ Around the Expansion Point a=1. Does My Approach Yield An Alternative Answer?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

Professor's Approach:

f(x)=$xe^x$            f(1)=$e$
f'(x)=$e^x+xe^x$      f'(1)=$2e$
f''(x)=$2e^x+xe^x$   f''(1)=3e

Resulting Taylor Series: $e+2e(x-1)+3/2e(x-1)^2$

My Approach:
Find the first degree Taylor Series for $e^x$ centered around a = 1

Let g(x)=$e^x$
$g^n(x)$ = $e^x$
Therefore all coefficients are e for a=1.

Result: $e+e(x-1)$

To find the second degree polynomial of $xe^x$ simply multiply the previous Taylor series by x.

Result: $ex^2$

The issue is that these two answers are not equivalent.
However, graphically, both are attempting to approximate $e^x$ around x=1.
Professor's Approach in Green, My Approach in Blue:
[graphical image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQGXI.png)

Although I probably will not get my points back for this midterm problem, I need some closure as to why my approach is incorrect(if it is). After all, I have seen my approach used for problems such as the Maclaurin series of $xcosx$.

Comment: How did you get the equation $f^n(x)=e^x$?

Comment: You need to multiply by $1+ (x-1)$. And also consider the second order term of the exponential. When you multiply the two expansions you can discard the cubic term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final answer is centered at $0$, not at $1$ so it doesn't really make sense. It is also wrong as you are missing part of the second order term as you will see below. You take the first order Taylor series of $e^x$:
$$ e^x = e + e(x-1) + O(x-1)^2$$
Multiplying by $x = 1 + (x-1)$ (so to get an answer centered at $1$) gives
$$ xe^x = e + 2e(x-1) + e(x-1)^2 + O(x-1)^2.$$
But this is NOT what you want as you are still missing part of your order two term. You need a second order Taylor series for $e^x$:
$$ e^x = e + e(x-1) + \frac{1}{2}e(x-1)^2 + O(x-1)^3. $$
Now when we multiply by $1 + (x-1)$ we get
$$ xe^x = e + 2e(x-1) + \frac{3}{2}e(x-1)^2 + O(x-1)^3$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would be

\begin{align}
xe^x& = (1 + (x-1)) e^{x-1} e \\
& =(1 + (x-1)) e ( 1 +(x-1) \\
& + \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2 + O(x-1)^3 )\\
& =e ( 1+(x-1) + \frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2 \\
& + (x-1)+(x-1)^2 +O(x-1)^3 )\\
& = \ldots
\end{align}

Comment: I see that this approach works but could you clarify how you moved from line 2 to 3?

Comment: I multipled the two polynomials. Term by term.