# Alternative Answer to Solving the Taylor Polynomial of Degree 2 for f(x) = $xe^x$ Around the Expansion Point a=1.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

Work:
Typical Approach -
f(x)=$xe^x$            f(1)=$e$
f'(x)=$e^x+xe^x$      f'(1)=$2e$
f''(x)=$2e^x+xe^x$   f''(1)=3e

Resulting Taylor Series: $e+2e(x-1)+3/2e(x-1)^2$

My Approach -
Find the first degree Taylor Series for $e^x$ centered around a = 1

Let g(x)=$e^x$
$g^n(x)$ = $e^x$
Therefore all coefficients are e for a=1.
Result: $e+e(x-1)$

To find the second degree polynomial of $xe^x$ simply multiply the previous Taylor series by x.

Result: $ex^2$
This comes about as the result of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty xe(x-1)^n/n!$

Justification:
If a Taylor Series Approximation's Goal is to approximate a curve around a point, then my approach achieves the end result as the typical approach.

Typical: Green Mine: Blue
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYSec.png)

If the image is not enough, WolframAlpha tests the series as a whole for equivalency to a function:
[equivalency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLod6.png)

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If you're not satisfied with the answers to your previous question, ask for clarification from the people who answered. Does this answer your question? [Solving the Taylor Polynomial of Degree 2 for f(x) = $xe^x$ Around the Expansion Point a=1. Does My Approach Yield An Alternative Answer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549827/solving-the-taylor-polynomial-of-degree-2-for-fx-xex-around-the-expansion)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer given to that earlier post had nothing to do with the question at hand and I am unable to downvote that response so....

Comment: You may want to explain that to the answerer, clarifying what you expect from them. Otherwise, all I can do is recommend you be patient. Reposting runs against the etiquette here.